# Ubuntu partition deleted and cannot boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I accidentally deleted my Ubuntu 14.04LTS partition lately (with Arconis Disk Director under Windows 7), now I cannot boot either into Ubuntu or Windows. After I start my computer, I will be brought to the Grub rescue mode. Typing "ls (hdX.msdosY)" for any X and Y gives me the response "Filesystem is unknown". I tried reinstalling Ubuntu with a USB stick, but as soon as I hit "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu" in the Ubuntu installer boot menu, the computer restarts. What can I do? Is it possible for me to recover my Ubuntu installation, or at least boot into my Windows installation?

More info on my Ubuntu installation: My laptop was preinstalled with Windows 7, and then I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. I have only one hard drive and I created a 100 GB logical partition for Ubuntu.

More info on how I deleted my Ubuntu partition: I was showing a friend how to expand the Windows C:  drive with Arconis disk director. My Ubuntu partition uses ext4 file system so it's shown as blank in Arconis. Without much thinking (since I have a few other unused partitions so seeing a blank partition didn't alarm me), I showed him how to delete that partition and use the released disk space to expand C:. Later when I was going to get back to work with Ubuntu, I found myself unable to boot! Neither Ubuntu nor Windows!

Comment: That doesn't sound too good... Have you tried running a different ISO on the flashdrive? I would suggest GParted.
<br>
<br>
http://gparted.org/livecd.php It's debian based like Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do? Is it possible for me to recover my Ubuntu
>   installation, or at least boot into my Windows installation?

There are couple of things you can do here.  I do not think you will be able to recover your Ubuntu installation as the partition was not just deleted but was also merged with existing Windows partition from Windows.  But yes, by all means, you should be able to recover your MS Windows installation.  You will need a Windows recovery bootable CD.  Once you boot from the Windows bootable recovery/repair CD, you can switch to a recovery environment and attempt to restore the MBR from there.

Windows 7 repair CD has a commandline utility called `bootrec` which can not only scan and tell you valid Windows installations on your machine but can also rewrite the MBR to help you boot into it.  I just dont have a Windows system handy so can't give you exact command but you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a live dvd/cd/usb to install in the empty space and when it installs grub2 it will (should) pick up windows and add it to the grub menu.